# Programmatically Set DataGrid.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have multiple `DataGrids` that store a unique ID, then multiple columns of information regarding that person, company etc. The `DataGrid` is stored with a `TabControl`, with a separate `TabItem` that is used to fill in details regarding the person/company. When the user clicks add, I would like to take them back to the first `TabItem`, and automatically select the new Item (person or company) that the user has added. The `DataGrids` are bound to `ObservableCollections`

I can already set the TabItem back using;

```
tabItem.IsSelected = true
```

Is there a way in which, after clicking add, I set the `TabItem`, loop through the items in the `DataGrid`, find the ID of the new item and set the `SelectedItem` to it? I would know the ID of the Item as I assign it to the person/company.

EDIT: I have tried using;

```
CompanyView.MoveCurrentTo(companyDetails);
```

CompanyView being the `CollectionView` and `companyDetails` the details of the Company the user added however this does not work.

Comment: If your DataGrid is bound to an `ObservableCollection`, you should just be able to cast `DataGrid.Items` to your collection to search it and find the right item to be selected. That said, depending on your overall design it would probably be better to bind the `SelectedItem` of your DataGrid to something on your object model, and set the object model value instead of messing with the UI object.

Answer (score 0):

You've said that you can set the `TabItem` back, so let's go further.

**To loop through items of `DataGrid`:**

```
int ID=5; //you said you know the ID field

var items = yourDataGrid.Items as ObservableCollection<CompanyModel>;
foreach (CompanyModel m in items)
{
     if (m.Id == ID)
     { 
        yourDataGrid.SelectedItem = item;                                   
        yourDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(yourDataGrid.SelectedItem);
        break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer however i am getting an error, `Unable to cast object of type 'SdcDatabase.Model.CompanyModel' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.`. The `CompanyModel` is just my Model type

Comment: The `.Items` property of the DataGrid should be the `ObservableCollection<CompanyModel>` of objects it is bound to, not the UI DataRow objects. If you want to find the actual UI objects, you'll probably need to use the `ItemContainerGenerator`. That said, if you cast it correctly you should be able to use a `foreach(var c in companyModels)` and test the Id property... if correct you can set the `.SelectedItem` to that object the way you have.

Comment: @Rachel in my view, OP develops code-behind application. Or it is not important?

Comment: @StepUp OP mentioned binding the .ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection, so the `.Items` property will be that object. If you were to set the `.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView`, then you could cast each object in `.Items` to a `DataRowView` like you have, but I never recommend that to any WPF developer :)

Comment: @StepUp It's not the worst I've seen, and it's going in the right direction :) Just change the cast from `DataRowView` to `CompanyModel` (might have to cast `yourDataGrid.Items` as well to `ObservableCollection<CompanyModel>`), change the way items are checked, and I don't know what you're trying to say with the event handler.... I'd just remove that unless you care to write up a much longer explanation on when and why you should use it :)

Answer (score 0):

The MVVM model lends itself excellently for situations like these.

If you bind to a collection you could catch the change before it is pushed to the collection in your setter with List.Except()

since you are binding your DataGrid to an ObservableCollection, you can add an additional binding for the SelectedItem and set the SelectedItem manually after you found the change and after the change was pushed to the Collection.

the choice of when you go back to the wanted TabItem is up to you.

Since you are binding the SelectedItem you will need to add

```
SelectionMode="Single"
```

The NotifyPropertyChanged(); is used because of the MVVM model

properties:

```
private Item _selectedItem;

public Item SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;

public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        var tempList = value.Except(_items).ToList();

        _addresses = value;

        //if you are 100% sure only one item will be added at a time, you can add .First()
        //edit: please also keep in mind you need to check if there is actually an item that was added. when items are removed, this would also try to change the SelectedItem
        SelectedItem = tempList.First();

        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

example wpf bindings:

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
>
```